# Having an a fragment communicate via interface to activity that did not launch it

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that communicates to an activity via an interface. This is cool and all but, is it possible to have the fragment communicate with an activity that did not launch it?

The reason why is I don't want one activity to be a million lines long of code implementing all interface methods for the fragments when I could just create "helper" activities to implement all the interfaces.

Currently I am using the Google Navigation drawer template so, maybe I could create new activities and group fragments around them. Im not sure if it will break my navigation drawer if I try to launch new activites.

Comment: "I have a fragment that communicates to an activity via an interface" -- consider a shared `ViewModel` instead. "I don't want one activity to be a million lines long of code implementing all interface methods for the fragments" -- this would be addressed by using shared `ViewModel` objects. It will be even better coming up when we can have `ViewModels` scoped to a particular navigation graph, but even now, you should consider having a fragment update a shared `ViewModel`, with the activity or other fragments observing `LiveData` in that `ViewModel` to find out about those updates.

Comment: @CommonsWare Im not too far into developing my app and will switch to the `ViewModel` way of designing/coding apps. Quite a bit to take in but, after a couple days of staring at a screen I should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the activity lifecycle parameters of an activity are usually separated of the activity. You can store them in the savedInstancestate and retrieve them back. This way you make sure that your activity has the right information when it is restored.

If content changes somewhere during the app lifecycle it is good to store that content somewhere permanently (SharedPreferences, Database, File).

If you want to notify several parts of your app of an event a good way to go is a Local Broadcast.

Having said that it seems strange to me that another activity than the currently running one (and the one containing your fragment) should be notified of an event. When it is resumed it would collect the necessary information and update itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking android development practices. `Fragments` are encapsulated within an `Activity`. And an `Activity` is encapsulated within itself. An `Activity` should not communicate with another `Activity` via references.

Activities are communicating via references here, so I totally would not recommend doing this. But here's how you can do what you're asking.

```
class HelperActivity { // implement here
    public static HelperActivity context = this;
    public MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment(this); // cast to implementation
}

class NormalActivity {

    void onCreate {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragment_attach, HelperActivity.myFragment)
        .commit();
    }
}
```